# Ilogger logs message and custom properties differently depending on log level

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, ilogger

so i encountered a situation where when logging message and custom dimensions with Ilogger in a function to Azure application insights / log analytics, my custom dimensions and my log message is placed and named differently. It seems to depend on if i log an Error or for example Information.

This is what i do:

**iLogger.LogInformation**

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> customDimentions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
customDimentions.Add("MessageId", metadataObject.MessageId);
customDimentions.Add("CorrelationId", metadataObject.CorrelationId);

using (iLogger.BeginScope(customDimentions))
{
    iLogger.LogInformation(message);
};
```

**iLogger.LogError**

```cs
IDictionary<string, object> customDimentions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
customDimentions.Add("MessageId", metadataObject.MessageId);
customDimentions.Add("CorrelationId", metadataObject.CorrelationId);

using (iLogger.BeginScope(customDimentions))
{
    iLogger.LogError(exception, message);
};
```

The results i get when querying the information in log analytics is:

First we can see that the logged information (marked "trace") has a message in the message field, but not the logged error (marked exception).
[image]

Secondly there is a difference in ware and ho how the custom dimentions are placed and named:

**iLogger.LogInformation**

[image]

**iLogger.LogError**

For logError it seems to log the incident twice once as "loglevel: Error" and once as "loglevel: Information", even though both are found withing the "exception" item type.

First exception item Type (loglevel:error):

[image]

First exception item Type (loglevel:information):

[image]

So to the questions then:

1. Why does the logger set "prop__" as a prefix on some of the custom properties and not for the exception itemType (logLevel:information)?
2. How come "message" isn't placed in the same level/column?
3. And depending if messaged is logged for error or information why does the property for message change name from "message" for "FormattedMessage"
4. Is there any way to keep any consistency in the log formatting so that information can be expected in various places?